# Reproject netcdf4 raster works for one dataset but not the other in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, netcdf

I wrote code to reproject the OISST NetCDF to my desired projection, and it works correctly.  However, when I run the same code on the NCEP NCAR Reanalysis data, I get something wrong.  Not sure why it works for one and not the other.

```
library(ncdf4) 
library(raster) 
library(rgdal)

nc_data <- nc_open('D:\\files\\slp.mon.mean.nc')
print(nc_data)

lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "lat", verbose = F)
t <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "time")
slp.array <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "slp")

r.slp <- raster(t(slp.array[,,773]), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))

projection <- CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs")
r.slp.lcc <- projectRaster(r.slp, rp, projection)
plot(r.slp.lcc)
```

where rp is a rasterLayer created from a polygon shapefile extent.

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 180, 180, 32400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 31.34677, 30.95615  (x, y)
extent     : 283.2476, 5925.667, -469.7869, 5102.319  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
```

[image: reprojected oisst data]

[image: reprojected ncep ncar data]

Source datasets:

[OISST data](https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov//Datasets/noaa.oisst.v2/sst.mnmean.nc)

[NCEP NCAR Reanalysis data](https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov//Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/Monthlies/surface/slp.mon.mean.nc)

Comment: Where is "slp.mon.mean.nc", because I can't see that in the folder you linked to? Do we assume the code generates the second plot from the "slp.mon.mean.nc" file because there's no actual "plot" calls in your code...

Comment: Not actually solving your problem, but have you tried {terra} instead of {ncdf4} using `read()` and `project("epsg: xxxx")`?

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks, I fixed the link to the dataset to point to the specific file instead and added the final plot line.

Comment: @dimfalk Thanks, your suggestion helped me explore options I didn't know existed.  :)